# Python plot heatmap from csv pixel file with panda

Tags: python, csv, heatmap, pixel

I would like to plot a heatmap from a csv file which contains pixels position. This csv file has this shape:

```
0 0 8.400000e+01
1 0 8.500000e+01
2 0 8.700000e+01
3 0 8.500000e+01
4 0 9.400000e+01
5 0 7.700000e+01
6 0 8.000000e+01
7 0 8.300000e+01
8 0 8.900000e+01
9 0 8.500000e+01
10 0 8.300000e+01
```

I try to write some lines in Python, but it returns me an error. I guess it is the format of column 3 which contains string. Is there any way to plot this kind of file?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

path_to_csv= "/run/media/test.txt"
df= pd.read_csv(path_to_csv ,sep='\t')
plt.imshow(df,cmap='hot',interpolation='nearest')

plt.show(df)
```

I tried also seaborn but with no success.
Here the error returned:

```
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `dtype=float` as a keyword argument of [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, sep='\t', dtype=float)
```

Or use [`pandas.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) :

```
plt.imshow(df.astype(float), cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')

plt.show()
```

##### # Output :

[image]

Comment: thanks for the time past to reply me. I did the modification as you adviced me, however, when I perform the code, it outputs me an error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1 0 0.000000e+00'`. Any idea?

Comment: Looks like the separator of you `.csv` is not the tab. Can you try this : `df= pd.read_csv(path_to_csv ,sep='\s', engine='python')` ?